# quadmath and argument type for scanf

Tags: c, scanf, quadruple-precision

I use the `<quadmath.h>`. With which argument type can I read my input correctly?
If I use double it looks like:

```
printf("enter 3 values for s, t and mt:\n");
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &s, &t, &mt);
printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", s, t, mt);
```

I tried different possibilities instead of "l" for example:

```
scanf("%Qf %Qf %Qf", &s, &t, &mt);
```

or even without

```
 scanf("%f %f %f", &s, &t, &mt);
```

however I get an error.

Comment: You need to post what error you get else it is difficult to answer.

Comment: which error are you getting? Don't use spaces in scanf.

Comment: @Rahul: Spaces in scanf are fine and well defined. They mean the input is to be read until space.

Comment: That is not really an error, but the input numbers are not recognized. Lastly I get -nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` (and related functions and `printf` and related functions) is *not extensible*. It can only parse what the standard library knows about. The C standard library comes with the operating system, not the compiler. It does not know about libquadmath, which is a compiler extension.

So you'll have to read strings and convert them separately using `strtoflt128`.

Note that C++ streams can be extended to extract `__float128`, but I don't see C++ interface in the quadmath library.

Comment: It means:

printf("enter 3 values for s, t and mt:\n");
scanf("%c %c %c", &s, &t, &mt);

and then

s= __float128 strtoflt128 ("s", NULL); 

and so on?

Comment: @user3305448 not `%c', use `%s`, and you should decalare `s`, `t`, `mt` as char array which is big enough to hold what you input.

Comment: @user3305448: Almost. String is `%s`, `%c` is just a single character and that's not enough. And you should really include the length limit, so it will be more like `%63s` (if you declare `char s[64]` and pass `s` as argument) or `%ms` (if you declare `char *s`, pass `&s` as argument and call `free(s)` afterwards). Beware that `%ms` is a GNU extension, but than quadmath is not portable either.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `%Qf` specifier in the `scanf`, you should input the high precision numbers as string, then use `strtoflt128` to convert. You also can't use `%Qf` specifier in the `printf`, use `quadmath_snprintf` to converts a `__float128` floating-point number into a string, then use `printf` with `%s` specifier to display it. Here is an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <quadmath.h>
int main()
{
        char s[256], t[256], mt[256];
        printf("enter 3 values for s, t and mt:\n");
        scanf("%s %s %s", s, t, mt);
        __float128 qs = strtoflt128(s, NULL);

        __float128 qt = strtoflt128(t, NULL);

        __float128 qmt = strtoflt128(mt, NULL);

        quadmath_snprintf(s, 256, "%Qf", qs);

        quadmath_snprintf(t, 256, "%Qf", qt);

        quadmath_snprintf(mt, 256, "%Qf", qmt);

        printf("%s %s %s", s, t, mt);
        return 0;
}
```

run the program:

> enter 3 values for s, t and mt:
>   3.4 4.5 5.6(enter)
>   3.400000 4.500000 5.600000