# Print __float128, without using quadmath_snprintf

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, precision, floating-point-precision

In my question about [Analysis of float/double precision in 32 decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629126/analysis-of-float-double-precision-in-32-decimal-digits), one answer said to take a look at `__float128`.

I used it and the compiler could find it, but I can not print it, since the complier can not find the header `quadmath.h`.

So my questions are:

1. `__float128` is standard, correct?
2. How to print it?
3. Isn't `quadmath.h` standard?

These answers did not help:

1. [Use `extern C`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571621/quadruple-precision-in-g-4-6-3-linux-using-quadmath)
2. [Precision in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451447/quadruple-precision-in-c-gcc)
3. [Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847735/quadmath-and-argument-type-for-scanf)

The [ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/I_002fO-Library-Routines.html#I_002fO-Library-Routines) also did not help.

Note that I do not want to use any non standard library.

[EDIT]

It would be also useful, if that question had an answer, even if the answer was a negative one.

Comment: As the leading underscores indicate: do not use it

Comment: Did you check the link I provided to the analysis? The answer says that it would be an option. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__float128` is a vendor extension.

---

In C23, `_FloatN` for `N = 16, 32, 64, 128` or multiples of 32 greater than 128 are standardised extensions that a compiler can provide. So `_Float128` would be the standard type. To print the type, you use `strfromfN` to turn it into a string:

```cpp
void print(_Float128 fp) {
    char buf[32 + sizeof(".e+99999")];
    int sz = strfromf128(buf, sizeof buf, "%.32g", fp);
    fwrite(buf, 1, sz, stdout);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E7W6a4r8d

---

In C++23, as well as `_FloatN` probably being provided as well by your compilers as an extension, `std::float128_t` is provided as the standard 128-bit float type.

It is implementation defined if there is an overload for `operator<<` so you can simply use `std::cout`, but there will be a `std::formatter` specialization, so `std::format` can be used to create a string:

```cpp
void print(std::float128_t fp) {
    std::println("{:.32g}", fp);  // std::println is C++26
    // C++23: `std::cout << std::format("{:.32g}\n", fp);`
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5sahahn4P

---

Before C23/C++23, there was no standard type for 128 bit float. Sometimes `long double` is 128 bits, but that is rare (it is more likely to be 80 bits or the same 64 bits as a regular `double`). So you had to use compiler extensions or a software emulation library.

Answer (score 2):

Using the boost library was the best answer for me:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;  

float128 su1= 0.33333333333333333q;
cout << "su1=" << su1 << endl;
```

Remember to link this library:

```
-lquadmath
```

Comment: And for those who insist on perfect precision, try this BCD library:
https://github.com/edwig/bcd
It's MS Windows specific but I hacked up my personal copy to remove the Windows dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not standard - neither the type nor the header. That's why the type has a double underscore (reserved name). Apparently, quadmath.h provides a `quadmath_snprintf` method. In C++ you would have used `<<`, of course.

Comment: No you can't. `__float128` will cause a syntax error when used with `<<`. Edit the answer and I will be happy to accept it, thanks. Or if you know how to make it work with `<<`, feel free to teach me(us).

Comment: @G.Samaras: I wrote "would" instead of "can" because it's a hypothetical - if `quadmath` was a C++ library, it would offer `<<`.

Comment: IMHO, your syntax is misleading. However the comment clears that. You seem to have the experience whether to edit or not. Accept and +1.

Comment: Fair point, it's easy to be too subtle on the Internet. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Work in GNU-Fortran! It allows to run the same program in different precision: single (32 bit), double (64 bit), extended (80 bit) and quad (128 bit). You don't have to do any changes in the program, you simply write 'real' for all floating points. The size of floating points is set by compiler options -freal-4-real-8, -freal-4-real-10 and -freal-4-real-16.