# How to print all the decimals of a float 128 to the console

Tags: c++, floating-point

I wanted to print the constant e, but I quickly came to realize, that cout cannot handle the `__float128`. Seeing as `__float128` cannot be printed, by the function. I also tried some solutions, available on the web, and all of them told me to convert it to a double. but that would lose the precision of the calculation.

I am using GCC x64.

the code:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <iomanip>
        #include <quadmath.h>
        #include <format>
        #include <charconv>

        volatile __float128 fact(unsigned int n)
        {
            long int fac=1;
            for (int x=n;x>1;x--){
            fac *=x;
            }
            return fac;
        }



        int main(){
        volatile __float128 e=0.0;
        for (int x =0;x<10000;x++){
        e +=1/fact(x);
        }
        std::cout<<e;
        }
```

As you can see, it does not print.

Comment: Why would you want to use `__float128` instead of `double` in the first place?

Comment: because of the larger amounts of decimals

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654693/print-float128-without-using-quadmath-snprintf)

Comment: Here is MCVE: https://godbolt.org/z/bYvsr8hxM

Comment: Format.h did not help the situation.

Comment: Did Boost's `float128.hpp` support help the situation?  If you need more decimals, have you considered BCD?

Comment: @cum-bria what kind of calculations need such high precision. In most cases even 80-bit `long double` is enough and is far faster than `__float128`

Comment: Because `fact` works on `unsigned int`, it'll overflow long before it gets to `fact(9999)`.

Comment: @Eljay I made the function non-recursive.

Comment: Because `fac` is a `long int`, the `fac` variable will overflow long before it gets to `fact(9999)`.

Comment: "all the decimals" makes no mathematical sense.  a `__float128` can accurately represent all decimal values to 36 _significant digits_.

Comment: "_because of the larger amounts of decimals_" - that is not really an answer.  What do you need that level of precision? Just curiosity?  Also it is about significant digits, not decimal places, and it is still only good for 36 decimal digits.  If you need more than you should consider an arbitrary precision math library, which presumably would include methods for presenting such values.  That will help with your flawed factorial also.  Don't expect binary floating point to work well if the actual value in decimal is critical - the conversion will make nonsense of significant digits beyond 36.

Comment: Side note: those `volatile`s don't contribute anything, and the code should have a `'\n'` after the output: `std::cout << e << '\n';`.

Comment: If you're worried about precision, your addition should start with the smaller values. (And note that even 1/3! can't be represented exactly as binary floating point at all.)

Comment: You are calculating this series in wrong way. Each element of series can be calculated based on precious element. You will gain on precision and speed. Also why you used `volatile` keyword at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++23 changed to_chars API to:

[std::to_chars - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars)

> ```cpp
> std::to_chars_result  
>     to_chars( char* first, char* last, /* floating-point-type */ value,  
>               std::chars_format fmt, int precision );
> ```
>
> (since C++23)

So looks like there is a way.

```cpp
    __float128 x = 1.123456789012345678901l;
    char buffer[256];
    std::to_chars(std::begin(buffer), std::end(buffer), x);
    std::cout << buffer;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sKdKxYKdG

But first I would test this fairly before using.

Also check if there are other changes which could use address this in alternative way. `std::format`/`std::print` should do it nicely too: https://godbolt.org/z/aMzfGM5vx

Comment: Alternatively, I presume this still works: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/libquadmath/quadmath_005fsnprintf.html

Comment: @Eljay this is C API, also I prefer to be closer to standard, even when using `__float128` compiler extension.

Comment: I just need to know what to use in place as my chars format argument?

Comment: @cum-bria what? Looks like you've skipped some vital information in a question. Please provide [mcve] in question.

Comment: after using your suggested function, it tells me that:
call of overloaded function to_chars() is ambiguos.

Comment: 1. You didn't enabled C++23 2. Or not using latest version of compiler which supports this C++23 feature.

Comment: This would be completely standard if you used `std::float128_t` from `<stdfloat>` (`__float128` is an alias for C23 `_Float128`, and `std::float128_t` is a type alias for `_Float128`, which is why this also works with `__float128`)

Comment: Nevermind, `__float128` is *not* a floating-point type, and is distinct from `namespace std { using float128_t = _Float128; }`. This `to_chars` overload isn't used, and a standard library extension function is used instead. `to_chars(char*, char*, std::float128_t)` is still standard though. https://godbolt.org/z/WcG59jvq6